# Getting error in flutter for setState while navigate to bottom menu

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:the_kitchen/constants/global_variables.dart';
import 'package:the_kitchen/services/bartanlist_page.dart';
import 'package:the_kitchen/services/bills_page.dart';
import 'package:the_kitchen/services/grocery_page.dart';
import 'package:the_kitchen/services/quotation_page.dart';
import 'package:the_kitchen/services/sabjilist_page.dart';



class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    const GroceryPage(),
    const QuotationPage(),
    const BillsPage(),
    const SabjiList(),
    const BartanListPage(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
//getting error here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohi3r.png)
    SetState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
       type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: GlobalVariables.secondaryColor,
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Dashboard',
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                backgroundColor:GlobalVariables.secondaryColor),
                
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Lists',
                icon: Icon(Icons.reorder_rounded),
                backgroundColor:GlobalVariables.secondaryColor),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Quotations',
                icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard_rounded),
                backgroundColor:GlobalVariables.secondaryColor),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Categories',
                icon: Icon(Icons.category),
                backgroundColor:GlobalVariables.secondaryColor),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Bills',
                icon: Icon(Icons.paste_rounded),
                backgroundColor:GlobalVariables.secondaryColor),
          ],
         currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQPzm.png)

i am getting error in flutter for setState while using in navigation routes for bottom navigation bar please help me with this.

and also help me with routes also for navigate all these 5 options.

error is saying  The method setState isn't define for the type 'HomeScreen'.
try correcting name to the name of existing method.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `setState` is only for `StatefulWidget`, you have a `StatelessWidget`. However you can easily transform it to one. In Android Studio at least you can right-click on the line with `class HomeScreen extends` then click on "Show Context Actions"-> "Convert to StatefulWidget".

Secondly, it is spelled with a small s. So `setState`, not `SetState`